# Why is the following code throws undefined index while uploading file in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

Marking the question as duplicate is futile, cause I've referred all such questions on SO and none of them did provide a solution.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name=$_FILES['filedoc']['name'];  
$temp_name=$_FILES['filedoc']['tmp_name'];  
if(isset($name)){
    if(!empty($name)){      
        $file=file_get_contents($temp_name);
        }
    }
else echo"Please upload file";

echo "<form action=\"";echo htmlentities($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);echo "\" method=\"post\">
    <h2>New Paste</h2>
    <label> Upload File?  <input type = \"file\" name = \"filedoc\"/></label><br><span class=\"error\">";echo $fileErr;echo"</span><br>
    <input id=\"button\"class=\"red\" type =\"submit\" class=\"red\" name=\"submit\" value = \"Paste\"/><br><span class=\"error\">";echo $submitErr;echo "</span>
    </form>";
}
?>
```

Form is being displayed correctly. So there are no errors in the second part. But then, I get this error ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: filedoc in *path of the file*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form also needs the following attribute: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. It specifies which content-type to use when submitting the form
Without the requirement above, the file upload will not work.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

form attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is missing

Comment: Thanks for the help!